# PHP taking just what I need from each element of an array

Tags: php

I was wondering how to take just what I need from each element of my array in php. I need just the parts between `">"` and `"<"` and can delete the rest.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Barton

Comment: Use `array_map` with a function that returns what you want from each element.

Comment: Show us a sample of your data

Comment: You are just one `array_map` call away from what you need. But you should show us your data, and most of all your previous attempts at solving your problem. [I just `array_reduce`d the precious 2 comments btw]

Comment: If you show us a example of your code you may get a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$abc="jbjbiubikub>hello<bhbb";

$new=explode(">",$abc);
$new=explode("<",$new[1]);
```

$new will print `hello`

Answer (score 0):

If the values in your array are stored this way: `<value>` or this way: `>value<`, you can write something like this:

```
<?php
function normalize($n)
{
    return(substr($n,1,-1));
}

$a = array('<value1>','<value2>');
$b = array_map("normalize", $a);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of `Regular Expressions`. Loop through the array elements , see if there is a match , If found, map them to a new array. Finally print the array.

```
<?php
$str= [">I will be printed<134","243234>Me too!<","3"]; //<--- Elements with text inside > and < 
foreach($str as $val)
{
    preg_match_all('/>(.*?)</', $val, $matches); //<-- Regex that matches content within > and <
    if(count($matches[1])!=0)
    {
     $arr[]=$matches[1];
    }
}

print_r($arr);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => I will be printed
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Me too!
        )

)
```